# Upload de diretórios/arquivos

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

A ideia e o StackOverflow disponibilizar a possibilidade de upload de diretórios de arquivos.

**Como funcionaria**

Quando o usuário postar uma dúvida, poderia anexar uma árvore de diretórios necessários para análise, como por exemplo arquivos `*.html, *.css`, `*.java, *.jsp` etc.

[image: Lista diretorios com checkBox]

**Como seria exibido**

Poderia seguir 1 dessas opções.

- Disponível para download "zip";
- Ser anexado junto aos post o conteúdo, como se fosse inserido na
  mão entre as tags de código , exatamente como é hoje;
- Nova tela especifica para exibição, com editores para apontar ou enviar a solução do problema em anexo a resposta.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eu até consigo entender o motivo pelo qual tal funcionalidade pode parecer interessante a princípio. Afinal, às vezes é trabalhoso elaborar uma pergunta e formatar todo o texto na mão, principalmente para quem ainda não se acostumou com as teclas de atalho e a sintaxe do *markdown* utilizado aqui.

Por outro lado, existem vários motivos pelos quais essa proposta não iria para frente e, depois de pensar um pouco, seria até indesejada.

- **Segurança**: enviar arquivos quaisquer e disponibilizar em formato zip iria aumentar muito o risco de execução de scripts maliciosos ou transmissão de vírus.
- **Complexidade**: criar "editores" não é algo trivial. No máximo talvez daria para adicionar coloração de sintaxe durante a edição. Já existe um editor simples para JavaScript, HTML e CSS, afinal eles são nativamente suportados pelos navegadores, mas para permitir edição de arquivos e outras funcionalidades seria muito trabalho para pouco resultado, pois não é o objetivo do site ter uma IDE.
- **Ninguém quer perguntas/respostas muito longas**: existe uma razão para o tamanho das perguntas e respostas ser limitado. Enviar um diretório com arquivos pode, a princípio, parecer facilitar a vida de quem pergunta. Porém, pense em quem vai responder. Ninguém aqui vai querer ler um programa inteiro, navegar por vários arquivos, entender tudo para depois tentar ajudar. O ônus de organizar o conteúdo cabe a quem vai perguntar, pois deve saber [extrair somente a informação relevante](/help/mcve).

Em resumo, ferramentas podem ajudar de uma forma ou de outra, mas desde que elas não induzam à "preguiça". Este é o ponto mais importante. Perguntas com muitos arquivos anexos só iriam aumentar a porcentagem que ficam sem resposta, levaria os usuários a postar muitos arquivos irrelevantes, seria, no mínimo, um desrespeito com o tempo das outras pessoas.

Minha dica é que aprenda a usar melhor as ferramentas que já existem, principalmente teclas de atalho. Além disso, quando postar uma pergunta, procure pensar sobre qual parte do seu código é ou não relevante ao invés de pensar que *quanto mais código, melhor*. Em pouco tempo você vai ver a diferença.

Comment: Não custa repetir: *O ônus de organizar o conteúdo cabe a quem vai perguntar, pois deve saber extrair somente a informação relevante.* Perfeito.